# Sql combining two column into one variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql command

```
SELECT A.*,
       K1.AD CONTACTAD,
       K1.SYD CONTACTSYD,
       KR.AD KURUM,
       K2.AD SUPERVISORAD,
       K2.SYD  SUPERVISORSOYAD,
       K3.AD REQUIRERAD,
       K3.SYD REQUIRERSOYAD
FROM  
       TD_ACTIVITY A,
       KK_KS K1,
       KK_KS K2,
       KK_KS K3,
       KK_KR KR
WHERE  A.INS_CONTACT_PERSON = K1.ID
   AND A.SUPERVISOR =  K2.ID
   AND A.REQUIRERID = K3.ID 
   AND A.INSTITUTIONID = KR.ID
```

I want to combine `CONTACTAD` and `CONTACTSOYAD` into one variable like `CONTACT`.How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried ... [concat](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm)?

Comment: @Alexander Thanks Alex.I had handled it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `||` for concatenating in oracle

```
SELECT A.*,
       K1.AD || K1.SYD as CONTACT,
       KR.AD KURUM,
       K2.AD SUPERVISORAD,
       K2.SYD  SUPERVISORSOYAD,
       K3.AD REQUIRERAD,
       K3.SYD REQUIRERSOYAD
FROM  
       TD_ACTIVITY A,
       KK_KS K1,
       KK_KS K2,
       KK_KS K3,
       KK_KR KR
WHERE  A.INS_CONTACT_PERSON = K1.ID
   AND A.SUPERVISOR =  K2.ID
   AND A.REQUIRERID = K3.ID 
   AND A.INSTITUTIONID = KR.ID
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Oracle concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)

```
SELECT A.*,
       K1.AD || ' ' || K1.SYD CONTACT
       KR.AD KURUM,
       K2.AD SUPERVISORAD,
       K2.SYD SUPERVISORSOYAD,
       K3.AD REQUIRERAD,
       K3.SYD REQUIRERSOYAD 
  FROM TD_ACTIVITY A,
       KK_KS K1,
       KK_KS K2,
       KK_KS K3,
       KK_KR KR 
 WHERE A.INS_CONTACT_PERSON = K1.ID 
       AND A.SUPERVISOR =  K2.ID 
       AND A.REQUIRERID = K3.ID 
       AND A.INSTITUTIONID = KR.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
SELECT A.*,
       concat(k1.ad, k1.syd) concat
       kr.ad kurum,
       k2.ad supervisorad,
       k2.syd supervisorsoyad,
       k3.ad requirerad,
       k3.syd requirersoyad
FROM   td_activity A,
       kk_ks k1,
       kk_ks k2,
       kk_ks k3,
       kk_kr kr
WHERE  A.ins_contact_person = k1.ID
AND    A.supervisor         = k2.ID
AND    A.requirerid         = k3.ID
AND    A.institutionid      = kr.ID;
```

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) to know more about `CONCAT` in Oracle.

Comment: @OracleUser, Yeah. I hope it'll work.

Comment: Alias only for the final `SELECT`ed expression? probably this `concat(k1.ad, k1.syd) concat`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT K1.AD || columnName "CONTACT"
```

Here columnName is name of column for which alias is `CONTACTSOYAD`.

You cannot operate on alias name in **same SELECT list** so below will give error

```
SELECT CONTACTAD ||  CONTACTSOYAD "CONTACT" , ...rest of columns...
FROM
..rest of query..
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
(K1.AD||K1.SYD) AS CONTACT
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**

```
select CONTACTAD || CONTACTSOYAD from emp;
```

|| is the concatenation operator in Oracle

hope this helps..